# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql

I am following the Moodle 3.0 dev installation.

In the database setting process there is an error:

```
Error: Database connection failed
```

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in `config.php`

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) inC:\Apache24\htdocs\moodle\lib\dml\mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 79
```

There is somebody who can tell me what to do in order to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must allow remote login on MySQL server to root user using the command below

### To allow from localhost

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

### To allow from anywhere

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

### To allow from some host **X.X.X.X**

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'X.X.X.X' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*root_user_password' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Note : Above command must be followed by `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`& restart on MySQL service

Comment: It might be better to be specific about the address you want to allow allowing AnYONE is a horrible idea!

Answer (score 1):

At the Linux or DOS prompt type

> mysql -u root -p

Then the following will create a new root user id which can be logged in from anywhere. It also drops already created root to remove the possibility of problems. Warning: this is not the best solution in a production environment.

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'P@ssw0rd';
grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
flush privileges;
drop user 'root'@'localhost';
drop user 'root'@'127.0.0.1';
drop user 'root'@'::1';
flush privileges;
```